# Django Auth Views login page displays no errors

Tags: html, django, jinja2

I am using Django Auth Views to implement my login page.

This is my url:

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name':'users/login.html'}, name='login'),
```

And this is the template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

  <div class="ui raised text container segment">
      <div class="ui horizontal divider">Login</div>
      <form method='POST'>
          <div class="ui form segment">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="required field">
                  {{ form.username.label }} 
                  {{ form.username }} {{ form.username.errors }}
              </div>
              <div class="required field">
                  {{ form.password.label }} {{ form.password }} {{ form.password.errors }}
              </div>
              <button class="ui primary submit button" name="submit_button" id="submit_button" type="submit">Login</button><br>

            Forgot your password? Click <a href='/password_reset/'>here</a>.

          </div>
      </form>
      <div class="ui bottom attached warning message">
            <i class="icon help"></i>
            Haven't signed up yet? <a href="/signup/">Signup here</a> instead.
          </div>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

When I type in a Password that I know is right, no error messages are shown.

Is there a fix for this?

Thanks

Comment: I dont understand the question here but error will come only after submit button click

Comment: Do you mean if the password is incorrect?

Comment: @cbuch1800 if the password doesnt match the email it doesnt display any errors

Comment: @Vaibhav see above

Comment: can you check output of  {{ form.non_field_errors }} and
{{ form.username.errors }} and {{ form.password.errors }} and {{form.errors}}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the message framework of django.contrib

```
def your_login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        //your logics here//
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Error! wrong username/password')

    return render(request, 'app/login.html')
```

and then in your template

```
{% if messages %}
<ul>
    {% for message in messages %}
        <li>{{message}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}

<form method='POST'>
      <div class="ui form segment">
          {% csrf_token %}
        //template logic//
</form>
```

This will show error messages along with the fields when type wrong email or password.